# Having problems in adding Bibliography to a report class in Texmaker

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, texmaker

i am writing my master thesis as a report document in Latex using Miketex 2.9 and Texmaker (pdflatex and biblatex) but i was unable to get bibliography added to my report as well unable to get the numbers through \cite{...} in the report. I always get the label name or a question mark. I don't know whats going wrong can anyone please help me were i am doing it wrong. I have \cite{} label name in my Introduction chapter and also i have used the my configure texmaker format as PdfLatex + Bilatex + pdflatex(x2) + pdfView .

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[german,english]{babel}
\usepackage[a4paper,width=150mm,top=35mm,bottom = 35mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{biblatex}
%\usepackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{rotating, graphicx}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}
\renewcommand*\contentsname{Table of Contents}


\makeatletter
\def\BState{\State\hskip-\ALG@thistlm}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\input{Titlepage}
\newpage
\input{Acknowledgement}
\newpage
\input{Abstract}
\newpage
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\newpage
\input{Introduction}

\input{AugmentedReality}


\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{References}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{References} %this is my .bib file created in the same folder 
                          % were my .tex exists               
\printbibliography


\end{document}
```

and this is my .bib file

```
@Article{cluster,
author = {Omar Alkhamisi and Muhammad Mostafa Monowar},
title = {Rise of augmented reality: current and future application areas},
journal = {Computer science and communications},
year = {2013},
OPTvolume = {Vol.1},
OPTnumber = {No.4},
OPTpages = {10},
OPTmonth = {November},
OPTnote = {Online, accessed 05-01-2016},
}
```

Comment: You are loading `biblatex` and `natbib`, but you should only be loading one of the two bibliography packages. You also use code from both packages, (`natbib`'s `\bibliographystyle{plain}` and `biblatex`'s `\printbibliography`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Moewe said, either you use `natbib` or `biblatex`, but not both. More precisely, if you want to use `natbib+bibtex`you need:

```
\documentclass12pt, twoside]{report}

………

%\usepackage{biblatex}
%\addbibresource{References.bib}
\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{document}

………

\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{References}
\nocite{*}
%\printbibliography
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{References}

\end{document}
```

For `biblatex+biber`, you'll use:

```
\documentclass12pt, twoside]{report}

………

\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{References.bib}
%\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{document}

………

\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{References}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
%\bibliographystyle{plain}
%\bibliography{References}

\end{document}
```

instead. If you want to emulate the `\citet` and `\citep` commands from `natbib`, add the `natbib` option on loading `biblatex`. However, there are equivalent commands already defined by biblatex. The default bib compiler for biblatex is `biber`, but you may choose `frontend=bibtex`, but you'll loose some functionalities.

Comment: #Moewe...thank u for your time i tried both the ways which is using only biblatex or natbib but still i couldn't find the right solution. I still couldnot get my references numbers at the place were i have \cite{} them. I can only see the name of the labels instead of numbers and no separate section or as a separate field for bibliography(References)....

Comment: @sravan Please check out [question mark instead of citation number](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864) and for `biblatex` + Biber also [Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864)

Comment: @sravan - Are you maybe not running BibTeX between LaTeX runs?

Comment: @Mico..no i have configured my build pdfLatex + Bib(la)tex + pdfLatex(x2)+viewpdf.. like this inorder not to forget the order but now i have disgusted with the problem, i tried everything what i can its almost 2 days i have wasted on it still i couldn't figure out whats going wrong....fu...g Texmaker...

Comment: Try this: 1) delete all auxiliary files 2) do the compilations (latex, bibtex/biber, latex, latex) individually and what happens. Is there a .bbl file created? What does the .blg file say?

Comment: #Bernard...I have done what u have said yes a .bbl file is been created but it is empty and .blg file is not generated at all...may i know why it couldn't able to generate .blg file....?

Comment: @sravan: Nothing appears  in the TeXmaker console when you launch `biber` after you've executed (pdf)latex once?

Comment: #Bernard.. I would say i was not clear with your question but do you mean this. I have opened my texmaker and had a build and checked the command prompt in the tools there is only the path i mean the drive\folder name...

Comment: This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit) The top-level auxiliary file: Thesis_structured.aux I found no \citation commands---while reading file Thesis_structured.aux I found no \bibdata command---while reading file Thesis_structured.aux I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file Thesis_structured.aux (There were 3 error messages)  i am getting this errors when i launch my main class with Bibtex....

Comment: @sravan: if I understansd well what you did, it's not exactly that: launch `pdflatex` from theTools menu (`F6` key), then `BibTeX/biber` (`F11`). Each time you'll see in the console  (what you call the `command prompt`) the log file (`.log` for `pdflatex`` , `blg` for `bibtex/biber`). In  the `blg`, you'll see if a  `.bbl` file was created. If it was, call pdflatex again twice. Furthermore, in order to launch `biber, not `bibtex`with the `F11` key, you have to configure TeXmaker for that (menu `Options > Configure TeXmaker > Commands`, write the relevant path in the `Bib(la)tex` line).

Comment: For your last post: `biblatex`, by default, uses `biber`, not `bibtex`. You have to configure TeXmaker for it (see previous comment).

Comment: #Bernard...No in my case it was options>Configure texmaker>Commands>Bib(la)tex>bibtex %...i have checked my configuration or do you want me to change it to biber % instead...?

Comment: #Bernard when i changed it to biber this is my scenario                                                          
INFO - This is Biber 2.3 INFO - Logfile is 'Thesis_structured.blg' INFO - Reading 'Thesis_structured.bcf' WARN - Warning: Found biblatex control file version 3.0, expected version 2.9 WARN - No data sources defined!

Comment: Do you have a `References.bib` file? B.t.w. you should update: `biber` has version no `2.4` and bilatex version `3.4`. Here is the beginning of my `.blg`: `
[0] Config.pm:340> INFO - This is Biber 2.4
[1] Config.pm:343> INFO - Logfile is 'pbbiblatex.blg'
[51] biber-MSWIN64:287> INFO - === 
[75] Biber.pm:347> INFO - Reading 'pbbiblatex.bcf'
[210] Biber.pm:738> INFO - Using all citekeys in bib section 0
[271] Biber.pm:3150> INFO - Processing section 0
[477] Biber.pm:3307> INFO - Looking for bibtex format file 'References.bib' for section 0`

Comment: The middle :
[733] bibtex.pm:1124> INFO - Decoding LaTeX character macros into UTF-8
[735] bibtex.pm:985> INFO - Found BibTeX data source 'E:/Tests/Biblatex/References.bib'
[788] UCollate.pm:65> INFO - Overriding locale 'en-US' defaults 'variable = shifted' with 'variable = non-ignorable'
[788] UCollate.pm:65> INFO - Overriding locale 'en-US' defaults 'normalization = NFD' with 'normalization = prenormalized'
[788] Biber.pm:3027> INFO - Sorting list 'nty/global' of type 'entry' with scheme 'nty' and locale 'en-US'
[788] Biber.pm:3031> INFO - No sort tailoring available for locale 'en-US'

Comment: And the end: `
[790] bbl.pm:519> INFO - Writing 'pbbiblatex.bbl' with encoding 'UTF-8'
[791] bbl.pm:615> INFO - Output to pbbiblatex.bbl`

Comment: You need to upgrade biber to version 2.4. That warning means that your biblatex is too new for your biber version. With biber version 2.5 (currently in development), this warning will be fatal and easier to understand.

Comment: #Bernard....finally i got it but thank you a lot for your suggestions for through out my questioning. I need to thank even moewe and PLK. The problem is with upgrading the manually added packages in my case biblatex. This source have helped me to find out the solution  (How should one maintain and update a MiKTeX installation?)